# The images saved in the DCIM folder in the SD card and the internal memory disappear after a while. Please help!

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, gallery, images

I am using LG G4.  This all started after my phone came back from the service center earlier this month with a brand new motherboard. I clicked a few pictures while on a trip and while playing around with the camera, I selected Manual setting and accidentally selected RAW jpg.  I switched back and continued clicking away.  After I came back, one fine day all the pictures were gone from the camera folder.

I tried software like recuva which are able to see that there over 3000 files but no software is able to retrieve the images.  All the images in other folders are fine. So this was in my SD card so I just figured that was the problem.

I was wrong, I stopped using the SD card and changed the storage to phone memory and it still continues.  It's like images disappear(unreadable) after a week I think.

I used ES file explorer to show the hidden files named .nomedia and delete them (currently in recycle bin).  I still cannot see the images.

I also read something about a jpg decoder library missing can be a reason.  All that fancy coding just scared me a little.

I am here to see if there is a solution.

My potential alternates are:

- Install a different camera app so the images are saved in a different
  folder
- Move the images everyday after they are clicked to a new folder.
- Reinstall the stock camera app somehow
- Factory reset

Please tell me if there is another way, I am desperate.  :( :(